# Can you access attributes that were created with the init method from other methods in the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, methods

When I write the `__init__` method and assign attributes, can I access those attributes in other methods (functions) that I write in that class? If so, how is it done?

I've googled this but couldn't find an answer. I Haven't been able to wrap my head around this one.

Comment: ... This would be clearer if you posted the code you have been trying that did not work, so we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: Check out the `self` keyword

Comment: @RoboMop `self` is not a keyword

Comment: "When I write the init method and assign attributes, can I access those attributes in other methods (functions) that I write in that class?" of course you can, that's *the whole point of attribute*. "If so, how is it done?" The same way you always access an attribute.

Comment: @RoboMop `self` is not a keyword. It's merely the name *conventionally* given to the first positional argument in a method, which will implicitly get passed the instance when the method is called on the instance

Comment: @khelwood What else would you call it?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, assigning attributes like `self.thing = 5` within `__init__` is _the_ way of storing data in the class, and obviously these attributes are accessible from other methods

Comment: @khel I'm going through a course. I don't really have any code to post. It's conceptual and theoretical at this point. I've asked the course instructor, but he hasn't responded.

Comment: @Goion A parameter? A variable? A name?

Comment: @ShaunBarbour Well if you're asking only theoretically, then the answer is "Yes you can".

Comment: @khelwood I didn't mean self in that context, I meant it as the reference to the object that's accessing the variables. Like `self.attribute`.

Comment: @Goion whatever it is, it isn't a keyword at all. A keyword is a reserved word which is generally used in a syntactic construct. e.g. `for` is a keyword, it is reserved, you cannot use it as a variable name, for example, `for = 42` is a `SyntaxError`. `self = whatever` is *always* perfectly valid Python.

Comment: @Goion, it's a regular variable. You could write `def __init__(my_fancy_name)`, and that would mean exactly the same as `def __init__(self)`

Comment: @RoboMop Yes, I know that's what you meant. It's not a keyword.

Comment: Okay wait this is getting out of hand. My terminology was wrong, thanks for correcting me, but this is getting way too in depth for a question of this size, I believe a simple google search of 'self in python' will solve OP's queries.

Comment: @khelwood yes, and it's an important distinction, because similar ideas *are* frequently keywords in other language, e.g. Java's `this` keyword

Comment: Ah. So we write `self` just because it is a convention. I wrongly assumed `self` is like `this`.

Comment: @Goion Yeah lmao I thought the same thing. Thanks everyone for correcting me, can't believe I'm still making silly mistakes like this after so long lol

Comment: Thank you everyone. Sorry if it was a simple question. I'm new at it. You guys have answered it. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self`:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'John'
    def other_method(self):
        print(self.name)
```

`other_method` will print "John".

Answer (score -1):

When you make a class and set an instance (like `first_class = MyClass()`) the `def __init__(self):` is run or initialised. Any variables in there, like `self.name` are able to be accessed from within the class and its functions, as well as when you use a class in another program. `self` kinda attaches that variable to that class.
Basically using Allure's example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "John"
    def show_name(self):
        print(self.name)
```

Then use `MyClass`'s name outside of class, in a program:

```
firstClass = MyClass()#Initialise MyClass and its variables
print(firstClass.name)
```

Or:

```
firstClass= MyClass()
firstClass.show_name()
```

Both output:

```
'John'
```

(still putting up this answer for others, hope you don't mind :)  )